# How to display dataextension data using amp script code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

how i display Data extension all records using amp script code.

```
 %%[
var @searchtermlookupValue
set @searchtermlookupValue = "Test" 
var @GetRows
set @GetRows = LookupRows("FFSubscribe","Last Name", @searchtermlookupValue)
var @GetRow, @GetRowCount
set @GetRowCount = rowcount(@GetRows)

if @GetRowCount > 0 then 

var @GetRowNumber
for @GetRowNumber = 1 to @GetRowCount do 

set @GetRow = row(@GetRows,@GetRowNumber) 

var @First_Name_Column
set @First_Name_Column = field(@GetRow,"First Name") 
var @Email_Address_Column
set @Email_Address_Column = field(@GetRow,"Email") 
]%%
First Name is %%=v(@First_Name_Column)=%% |  Last Name is 
%%=v(@Last_Name_Column)=%% |  Email is %%=v(@Email_Address_Column)=%%
<br/>
<hr/>
%%[
next @i ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variables to the URL that takes you to the landing page, and then when you're on the landing page you need to use either RequestParameter or QueryParameter to get the from the URL.

That is the only other way to do it, if you do not want to do a lookup.

Alternatively, you need to use the API.